# System of two non-linear equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:
\begin{align}
\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)&=1.6, \\
\cos(3\alpha)+\cos(3\beta)&=0.
\end{align}

How can i use an iterative method to solve these equations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Do you mean $$\cos(3\alpha_1)+\cos(3\alpha_2)=0$$ and $$\cos(\alpha_1)+\cos(\alpha_2)=1.6$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the triple angle formula,

$$\begin{cases}a+b&=p,\\4a^3-3a+4b^3-3b&=q.\end{cases}$$

Eliminating $b$,

$$12pa^2-12p^2a+4p^3-3p-q=0$$

is a mere quadratic equation.

With the given numerical values,

$$\cos\alpha=a=\frac{24\pm\sqrt{33}}{30}.$$

By symmetry,

$$\cos\beta=b=\frac{24\mp\sqrt{33}}{30}.$$